# C do-while loop

Tags: c, do-while

I'm trying to write a program with do..while loop for: list all the numbers from 100 downwards that are dividable by 7 and 5 but not 11.
can you help me?

Comment: Do you mind showing us what have you tried?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Please add a tag if it is.

Comment: Please 1) show us your code so far for the "do/while" loop 2) Q: How can you tell if a number is divisible by 7?  Divisible by 5?  Divisible by both 5 and by 7?  Hint: are you familiar with the "%" operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work, I haven't tested it or timed it and there are probably better ways of doing it speed wise, but:

```
int counter = 0;// Counts the index of the array
int num = 100;// the iterator like 'i' in a for loop
int nums [100];// the array to store all the numbers
do {
    if (num % 7 == 0 && num % 5 == 0 && num % 11 != 0) {
        nums[counter] = num;
        counter++;
    }
    num--;
} while(num >= 0)
```

Also here is a page with some stuff about do...while if you just need to study about it:

http://www.keil.com/support/docs/1950.htm

---

**Edit** ([sehe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85371/sehe)) *I couldn't let my hard work go to waste, could I:*

For absolute fun and kicks, here is my pythonist response in C++0x

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/phoenix.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::adaptors::filtered;
using boost::phoenix::arg_names::arg1;
using boost::irange;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    for (auto i : irange(200,1,-1) | 
        filtered(!((arg1 % 5) | (arg1 % 7)) && (arg1 % 11)))
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why did sehe put that in my post? I don't think it makes sense in the question and I don't see how it goes into my post

Comment: BTW, this is equal to `num % 35 == 0 && num % 11 != 0` since 5 and 7 are primes.

Comment: Well that would have made it harder to understand what I was doing

Comment: I agree, yet it is worth mentioning :)